# What is $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ is calculus?

Tags: calculus

I'm working through some derivative problems and the question is asking to describe all the relative extrema of f(x) = $xe^{-x}$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

And I'm not sure what R even is. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you mean the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $\Bbb R$ (or sometimes $(-\infty,\infty)$) is used to denote the set of all real numbers, as opposed to a subset like $[a,b)$.

Comment: Oh right, what would that mean in the context of this question? And what if the question said R2 or R3 instead? I have no idea what the difference is between the three. Thanks for your help

Comment: The entire Real number line.

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is the set of all $n$-dimensional vectors. Hence $\mathbb R$ is the set of real numbers, $\mathbb R^2$ is the plane, etc.

Comment: what would that mean in the context of this question? And what if the question said R2 or R3 instead? I have no idea what the difference is between the three. And what is R3? Thanks for your help

Comment: $\mathbb R^3$ would be 3-dimensional space
It means the function is defined on the real numbers.
The question could not ask you $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$ because the function is not defined in that domain.